# integration's extremes

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I apologize in advance for the question. I have $\int_{-1}^{1}xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx =\int_{...}^{...}xe^{-t}\frac{dt}{x}$ but…

- if $x=-1\Rightarrow t=\frac{(-1)^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$
- if $x=1\Rightarrow t=\frac{(1)^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Does this mean that the integral is zero?

Comment: The integral of any odd function over an interval symmetric about $0$ is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your answer. Instead, I know that the integral of an even function can be decomposed as $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$. Thus, my problem is now to calculate that $2\int_{0}^{1}x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

More basically $I=\int_{-1}^{1} x e^{-x^2/2} dx=0$ because the integrand is an odd function and the limits are symmetric.

When in an integral both the limit become the same after using a substitution, you need to reduce the interval: $(-a,a) \to (0,a)$, as
$$J=\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a}[f(x)+f(-x)] dx~~~~(1)$$
so if $f(-x)=-f(x)$, then $J=0$

Another way to reduce the interval of integration is:
$$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{\pi} [f(x)+f(2a-x)] dx~~~~~(2)$$
For example $$K=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sec^2 x}{4+\tan^2 x} dx$$
If you take $t=\tan x$, both the limits become identically equal to zero.
This does not mean that $K$ is essentially zero.
But if you apply (2), we get $$K=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \frac{\sec^2 x}{4+\tan^2 x} dx=
2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{4+t^2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{t}{2}|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral is zero:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x e^{-\frac {x^2} 2 } dx = \int_{0}^1 x e^{-\frac {x^2} 2 } dx +\int_{-1}^0 x e^{-\frac {x^2} 2 } dx $$

but
$$\int_{-1}^0 x e^{-\frac {x^2} 2 } dx \overset{x = -y}{=} - \int_{0}^1 y e^{-\frac {y^2} 2 } dy $$

Therefore

$$\int_{-1}^1 x e^{-\frac {x^2} 2 } dx = 0$$